# MainActivity onCreate called twice in TargetSDK 33 and minSDK is 24

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am trying to understand why Main launcher activity is launched twice as soon as I install the application for the first time.

I Just created empty activity and added activity life cycle logs.

Any Idea, What could be the cause of this?

**Here is my Activity code:**

```
package com.ninja.myapplications;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "Debug";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause");
    }
}
```

**Here is Manifest.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplications"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here is the build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.ninja.myapplications'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ninja.myapplications"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

**Here is the output**

[image]

Note: I tried with **singleTop** and **singleInstance** as a launchMode in that launcherActivity. but that didn't work.

Comment: Looks like a configuration change (orientation change or similar). The normal case of one `Activity` launching another `Activity` has the `onCreate()` of the new `Activity` occurring BEFORE the `onDestroy()` of the old one. Only in a configuration change will you see `onDestroy()` followed by `onCreate()`.